# In PyCharm, Ctrl+Enter reruns the code instead of split line. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm new to python and PyCharm of course. I use *Ctrl+Enter* to split line in editor (making new lines without moving the caret to the next line). But since yesterday it doesn't work anymore and *Ctrl+Enter* reruns the code instead of splitting the line. **Please help me fix that**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!!!
When the **#:Run** tab is open, *Ctrl+Enter* splits the line.
But when the **Python Console** tab is open, *Ctrl+Enter* reruns the code.